# Getting subprocess32 error on Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I am getting the following error popup even if I just hit the space inside the document:
plugin_host has exited unexpectedly, plugin functionality won't be available until Sublime Text has been restarted

```
log shows the following:
DPI scale: 1
startup, version: 3065 windows x32 channel: stable
executable: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe
working dir: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text 3
packages path: /C/Users/Асель/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages
state path: /C/Users/Асель/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Local
hardware concurrency: 4
zip path: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/Packages
zip path: /C/Users/Асель/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages
found 13 files for base name Default.sublime-keymap
found 2 files for base name Default.sublime-mousemap
found 11 files for base name Main.sublime-menu
loading bindings
loading pointer bindings
found 1 files for base name Soda Light 3.sublime-theme
theme loaded
app ready
startup cache, total files: 353 cache hits: 353
pre session restore time: 0.349854
startup time: 0.409854
first paint time: 0.429854
launching: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/plugin_host.exe
reloading plugin Default.block
reloading plugin Default.comment
reloading plugin Default.copy_path
reloading plugin Default.delete_word
reloading plugin Default.detect_indentation
reloading plugin Default.duplicate_line
reloading plugin Default.echo
reloading plugin Default.exec
reloading plugin Default.fold
reloading plugin Default.font
reloading plugin Default.goto_line
reloading plugin Default.history_list
loaded 1000 snippets
reloading plugin Default.indentation
reloading plugin Default.kill_ring
reloading plugin Default.mark
reloading plugin Default.new_templates
reloading plugin Default.open_file_settings
reloading plugin Default.open_in_browser
reloading plugin Default.pane
reloading plugin Default.paragraph
reloading plugin Default.paste_from_history
reloading plugin Default.save_on_focus_lost
reloading plugin Default.scroll
reloading plugin Default.set_unsaved_view_name
reloading plugin Default.side_bar
reloading plugin Default.sort
reloading plugin Default.swap_line
reloading plugin Default.switch_file
reloading plugin Default.symbol
reloading plugin Default.transform
reloading plugin Default.transpose
reloading plugin Default.trim_trailing_white_space
reloading plugin CSS.css_completions
reloading plugin Diff.diff
reloading plugin HTML.encode_html_entities
reloading plugin HTML.html_completions
reloading plugin AdvancedNewFile.AdvancedNewFile
reloading plugin BracketHighlighter.bh_core
reloading plugin BracketHighlighter.bh_logging
reloading plugin BracketHighlighter.bh_plugin
reloading plugin BracketHighlighter.bh_regions
reloading plugin BracketHighlighter.bh_remove
reloading plugin BracketHighlighter.bh_rules
reloading plugin BracketHighlighter.bh_search
reloading plugin BracketHighlighter.bh_swapping
reloading plugin BracketHighlighter.bh_wrapping
reloading plugin BracketHighlighter.ure
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.ColorHighlighter
reloading plugin Color Highlighter.colors
reloading plugin Emmet.emmet-plugin
reloading plugin EncodingHelper.EncodingHelper
reloading plugin Git.add
reloading plugin Git.annotate
reloading plugin Git.commit
reloading plugin Git.diff
reloading plugin Git.flow
reloading plugin Git.git
reloading plugin Git.history
reloading plugin Git.repo
reloading plugin Git.stash
reloading plugin Git.status
reloading plugin Git.statusbar
reloading plugin HyperlinkHelper.link_to_wikipedia_page_for_selection
reloading plugin HyperlinkHelper.lookup_with_google_and_link
reloading plugin HyperlinkHelper.wrap_selection_as_link
reloading plugin Nettuts+ Fetch.Fetch
reloading plugin Package Control.Package Control
reloading plugin ReadmePlease.ReadmePlease
reloading plugin SideBarEnhancements.Edit
reloading plugin SideBarEnhancements.SideBar
reloading plugin SideBarEnhancements.SideBarDefaultDisable
reloading plugin SideBarEnhancements.StatusBarFileSize
reloading plugin SideBarEnhancements.StatusBarModifiedTime
reloading plugin HTML-CSS-JS Prettify.HTMLPrettify
reloading plugin SublimeCodeIntel.SublimeCodeIntel
plugins loaded
Emmet: No need to update PyV8
reloading Packages/User/Fetch.sublime-settings
Could not import subprocess32 module, falling back to subprocess module
error: plugin_host has exited unexpectedly, plugin functionality won't be available until Sublime Text has been restarted
```

Is there any workaround for this, I really have no idea how to solve this issue. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed that you've got the plugin SublimeCodeIntel installed.

The GitHub page of the package contains an issue ([#328](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel/issues/328)) stating: 
`That message is only a warning. Don't pay attention to it.`

I could imagine there are more packages using the same `subprocess32` module, but the error seems to be the exact same text as the issue of SublimeCodeIntel suggests.

As your `plugin_host` crashes after this error, it is possible the error occurs due to this package, you might try upgrading or disabling the package (or removing the package files if you cannot start Sublime).

When that does not help, try updating to [the latest version of Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) (build 3065 or higher), which may just contain the fix (`Fixed a crash in plugin_host`).

If it's not SublimeCodeIntel, you might want to disable (quite a lot of work) each installed package one by one, and see if that solves the issue. I would suggest making a back-up of your current settings, so you can delete and/or disable whatever you like. Alternatively, you could make a list of packages, and start with a clean install and reinstall the packages one at the time.

Comment: Thank you so musch, I removed SublimeCodeIntel, that solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution, without disabling usable features is to install package control
https://packagecontrol.io/installation.

Go to `Package Upgrade` then select `SublimeCodeIntel`

Then Restart the SublimeText3.